# How to click on GWT enabled elements using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I'm working with Selenium as a newbie and also as a newbie developer.
I try to solve this XPath but with no results that is why I'm looking for help.

So I want to click in the checkbox which has a dynamic id but it is not that easy to find this checkbox based on tittle="Viewers"

Please notice there is a whole list of checkboxes with names on right from a checkbox in div which I want to include in my tests.

HTML:

```
<span class="row-selection"><input type="checkbox" value="on" id="gwt-uid-2215" tabindex="0"><label for="gwt-uid-2215"></label></span> <div class="row-label" title="Viewers">Viewers</div>
```

Snapshot;

[image: Provided code]

Comment: by id would be best... is the id random?

Comment: Yes id is random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/overview.html) enabled element so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* based on *title* attribute:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@title='Viewers']//preceding::span[1]//label"))).click()
  ```
- Using *xpath* based on *innerHTML*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Viewers']//preceding::span[1]//label"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```