# How to find GWT element with specific text next to it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

So I try to improve me code and XPATH and I try to handle field like this:

```
<div class="h3">Login</div> <div class="Is3WC-spot Is3WC-spotInfo icon xdm icon_information_16 dialogInfoSpot" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"><div class="Is3WC-spotRelativeDivPos"> <div class="Is3WC-spotTextMargins">User Name (login) must:<br>- contain at least 3 characters<br>- be shorter than 60 characters</div> <div class="Is3WC-spotClose icon hover xdm icon_delete_minor_white"></div> </div></div> <div class="floatLeft"><div><input type="text" class="dialogTextBox error"></div> <div class="Is3WC-errorLabel">Login is required.</div></div> <div class="dialogInformationIcon iconInformation clickable"></div>
```

How to create that xpath better?
[Login cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNSUq.png)

It works now as : `"/html/body/div[8]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/input"` and I'm not proud of it at all...

And a question about WebDriverWait. In topic [How to click on GWT enabled elements using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880706/how-to-click-on-gwt-enabled-elements-using-selenium-and-python/62890107?noredirect=1#comment111219808_62890107) one person recomend me to use WebDriverWait but I did own method:

```
@staticmethod
def clickPerform(driver, xpath):
    counter = 0;
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
            break
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            time.sleep(1)
            if counter == 10:
                Verify.verifyAssert(True, False,"Not able to click ElementClickInterceptedException: " + xpath)
                break
            counter = counter + 1
        except ElementNotInteractableException:
            time.sleep(1)
            if counter == 10:
                Verify.verifyAssert(True, False,"Not able to click ElementNotInteractableException: " + xpath)
                break
            counter = counter + 1
```

It is better to use the mentioned WebDriverWait instead of my method? (I think it is :)) but I'm looking for opinions )

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to write xpath relative to text here. You can try

```
//div[text()='Login is required.']/preceding-sibling::div/input

OR

//div[text()='Login is required.']/parent::div//input[contains(@class,'TextBox')]
```